# Nodes equation: can't find formula.

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion, trees, recursive-algorithms

Given the level $N$ at which a node $X$ is located in a binary tree, to search for node $X$ according to level-order traversal, we can use the knowledge of level $N$ where $X$ is located to narrow our search by using the formula $2n-1$ where $n$ is the level at which node $x$ is located.

But, I could not find the equation for the following one.

Suppose in the above case we only change the type of traversal to be post-order traversal, can we use a similar method to narrow down our search? In other words, by knowing the level $N$, what are the number of nodes we should narrow our search on according to post-order traversal?